# Insert content into editable div using ckeditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ckeditor

I'm making a web app using the CkEditor for some neat wysiwyg editors. On page load the page gets a couple of strings from a database using AJAX. How do I insert the strings into the div that is editable? I don't want to use a textarea because the inline editor looks much better with divs and require less work then.

I've tried the following scripts without success:

The first one tries to add the data to the div that becomes editable.

```
$('#awayList').append(data.boxOneCont);
```

And the second one I found here on stack overflow but that doesn't work either.

```
CKEDITOR.instances["awayList"].setData("Hej");
```

The connection with the db works perfectly, so the problem lies somewhere else.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with this:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData( '<p>Some other editor data.</p>', {
    callback: function() {
        this.checkDirty(); // true
    }
} );
```